# Access structure element by offset incorrect?

Tags: c++

I wrote a piece of demo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    int32_t total;
    int32_t a, b;
}__attribute__((packed));

void foo(struct S *s) {
    int32_t *v1_p = (int32_t *)(s + offsetof(S, b)); 
    cout<<"size is "<<sizeof(struct S)<<" offset is "<<offsetof(S, b)<<endl;
    cout<<*v1_p<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.total = 100;
    s.a = 200;
    s.b = 200;
    foo(&s);

    return 0;
}
```

The structure removed the padding and the printout message is:

```
size is 12offset is 8
32766
```

As you can see, the size of the structure is correct, and the offset is also correct. But value is not! I am so confused why this can happen?

update:

```
I changed  
int32_t *v1_p = (int32_t *)((char*)s + offsetof(S, b));
```

works!

I made this stupid mistake with pointer arithmetic :(

Comment: `s` is a `S*`. The way pointer arithmetic works, `s + 1` will point to a location in memory `sizeof(s)` away, not `1` byte away. Your updated method is one way of converting `s` into something where you can use `+` to add a distance in bytes.

Comment: The problem here is, as you've already figured out, that 's' is still of type 'struct S'. As such, adding anything to this pointer, will automatically add 'x times the size of struct', as if it was an array.

Comment: When `s` is a pointer, `s + i` is equivalent to `&s[i]`. You probably already know this, but forgot about it because of the context.